# Solutions...there are many

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

Saw this on the web somewhere...gave it a couple looks before an answer appeared. But it took a few more looks to determine that one answer wasn't exactly the limit to what we can juice out of this thing.

Rules:

- Don't post the same answer as the person before you

  (So I guess that means for the first time ever, looking at somebody else's answer is more than encouraged :p )
- The most impressive/most voted answer will be checkmarked

[image: []]

Comment: If you don't know the answer to your question, then you should state it in your post. Questions should be in general *uniquely* answerable, otherwise they tend to be too broad.

Comment: Considering that this question's sole purpose is to gather many answers, it is too broad. Puzzle questions should ideally have one answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer should be

> 4

because

> The numbers represent multiplication:
>
>    `9 2 1 8  —>  9 * 2 = 18`
>    `6 4 2 4  —>  6 * 4 = 24`
>    `5 7 3 5  —>  5 * 7 = 35`
>    `8 8 6 ?  —>  8 * 8 = 64`

---

### Testing more patterns

At first sight, you could also find that

> `9 2 1 8  —>  9 + 1 OR 8 + 2 = 10`
>    `6 4 2 4  —>  6 + 2 OR 4 + 4 = 8`
>    `5 7 3 5  —>  5 + 5 OR 7 + 3 = 10`

but this is broken by the last line

> `8 8 6 ?  —>  8 + 8 OR 8 + 6 don't give 10 or 8`

Comment: I was thinking a bit similar to you. But instead of adding. I subtracted 9 and 2, 1 and 8 which would be 7. 6 and 4,  4 and 2= 2. 5 and 7, 5 and 3= 2. 8 and 8, 6 and 6 = 0

Comment: I was also thinking that if you started on the second horizontal row, subtracted 4 and 2, and added 6 and 4. 10 - 2 equals 8, which is present on the last box of the first horizontal row. Third row and fourth row is different. It's 7 subtracted to 3, and 5 subtracted to 5. 4 - 0 is 4. 4 is present on the last box of the second row. Fourth row is 8 subtracted to 6 is 2, 8 subtracted to 1 is 7. 7 subtracted to 2 is 5. 5 is present on the last box of the 3rd row